# InfluxDB in Docker Bad gateway

Tags: docker, grafana, influxdb

I started setting up my Smart Home System in Docker with Openhab, mosquitto, Grafa etc. The Docker topic is still relatively new to me and I have not managed to connect InfluxDB with Grafana. Whenever I try, Influxdb: Bad Gateway appears. I did a lot of research on the Internet, but I couldn't find a solution that could help me. Maybe someone knows the problem and can help me.
Here is my docker-compose file:

```
influxdb:
image: influxdb:latest
container_name: influxdb
restart: always
ports:
  - 8086:8086
environment:
  - INFLUXDB_DB=telegraf
  - INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf
  - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true
  - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin
  - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=Welcome1 
volumes:
  - influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb

grafana:
   container_name: "grafana"
   image: "grafana/grafana:latest"
   restart: always
   ports:
    - 3000:3000
   volumes: 
    - ./grafana:/var/lib/grafana
```

Answer (score 4):

Grafana+InfluxDB datasource setup dialogue propose `http://localhost:8086` as default for URL field. This is a suggestion to leave it like this, being grafana and influxdb indeed on the same host

[image]

And this results in the *BAD Gateway* error.

Problem is they are also two *services* inside docker and they should refer each other through the name of their docker compose sections so, in your case, like this

[image]

Regarding your volumes sections, the one in influxdb declaration probably should have been:

```
volumes:
    - ./influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
```

to map the container folder `/var/lib/influxdb` to the host folder `./influxdb`, next to the `./grafana` one but this is not related to the *BAD Gateway* issue.

Answer (score 0):

volumes section was missing. Here is the working one.

```
version: '3'
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:latest
    container_name: influxdb
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 8086:8086
    environment:
    - INFLUXDB_DB=telegraf
    - INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf
    - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true
    - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin
    - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=Welcome1
    volumes:
    - influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb

  grafana:
    container_name: "grafana"
    image: "grafana/grafana:latest"
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    volumes:
    - grafana:/var/lib/grafana
volumes:
  influxdb:
  grafana:
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I was able to solve the problem. I also had to use the container name instead of localhost in grafana.

Comment: @fps_boost that's great!!! you can mark this issue as solved & upvote the solution.