# DockerCompose-Grafana-InfluxDB-Error: Bad Gateway

Tags: docker-compose, grafana, influxdb, bad-gateway

I know there are some similar questions in the forum, but nothing worked really out.
I try to connect grafana and influxdb with a dockercompose File, but everytime i get a Bad Gateway error. Here is the file:

```
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - grafana_network
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    depends_on:
      - influxdb


  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:latest
    container_name: influxdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    networks:
      - grafana_network
    volumes:
      - influxdb_data:/var/lib/influxdb
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=grafana
      - INFLUXDB_USER=grafana
      - INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=password
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin 
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password 
networks:
  grafana_network:
volumes:
  grafana_data:
  influxdb_data:
```

[Bad Gateway Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tteR5.png)

I already changed influxdb to localhost or ipaddress, nothing helped Only the Error changed to Bad Request.. Any recommendations?

Big Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add link to the other posts you saw. Also consider explaining why they did not work/apply to your case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65050546/influxdb-in-docker-bad-gateway here is for example a similar question. 1. I tried to change from localhost to influxdb or my ipaddress but nothing worked. 2. volumes section is in my dockerfile, Maybe you have some other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem.

[Selecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFtrJ.png) the Query Language `Flux` instead of `InfluxQL` worked for me.

Don't forget to use the URL http://influxdb:8086 as this is the name of your InfluxDB-service within docker compose.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I think Flux works for Influxdb OSS 2.0.                                                                 In my case changing the image to an older version worked out:                                                                                             `image: influxdb:1.8-alpine and image: grafana/grafana:7.5.4` in the docker-compose file solved the problem.